# Bootstrap 4 - Which is the main css/scss for customization; steps?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, customization

I'm trying to learn Bootstrap 4 and scss (first touch to both ever) and I'm feeling extremely dumb. So at the moment, I'm trying to change my body background-color. Tried at the variables.scss, bootstrap.css, _reboot.scss, bootstrap-reboot.css, but nothing ... at the console it's still written that the background is white (loaded by _reboot.scss:53).

So where and how I should apply my changes - backgrounds, colors, fonts, borders, etc.... thought it would be like less, css but this is scary ...

Thank you.

Comment: Make sure you're recompiling the scss

Answer (score 0):

Best practice for updating core bootstrap styles is to import bootstrap styles into your own file and edit classes there.  Then your classes will override bootstrap styles and it will allow for future bootstrap updates to not cause your customization to break.  Create a new .scss file and at the very top put:

```
@import "/bootstrap.scss";

body {
    background-color: red;
}
```

And then link to your new file in your source instead of the bootstrap files.  You'll still need bootstrap's js files.

If you do not want to follow best practices the other solution to your issue would be to just create a .css file and reference it after all bootstrap file are loaded.  That will override bootstrap styles without having to import bootstrap styles.  Not as clean and versatile for the future but might be easier for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Eric. 
I've created as you said new .scss file. I've linked it at the html and left only the bootstrap.min.css. But still there is no result - getting the body background from _reboot.scss.

Comment: you are compiling your .scss files correct?  .scss files need to be compiled into .css for the browser to be able to read them.  If you are not compiling your .scss then you should try my second suggestion.

Comment: It gives me this error while compiling: 
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
        on line 10 of Users/petko/Desktop/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss
>> @import "mixins";
   --------^

Comment: Sounds like your issue is with your compiler then.  Does mixins.scss live in the same folder as bootstrap.scss?  Have you always gotten that error?  When did it start?

Comment: Yes. The new (mine) .scss, bootstrap.scss, _mixins.scss and mixins folder, all are together at the default scss boostrap folder. First time. :(
Using Live Sass Compiler at VS Code.

Comment: Do you have to use sass?  Could you use the distribution files from bootstrap and then just create a .css file to update your styles (the second suggestion I had in my answer)?  If you need to use sass then I'd open another question about your compiler issues.  Until that is solved the rest of this won't work.